# Upgrade to a tankless heater

Tags: water, heater, tankless

My water heater went out and I'd like to replace it with a tankless. Electrical setup is as follows:

A.O.Smith 50gal water heater - 1, 30amp double pole breaker

Tankless needs - 2, 40amp double pole breakers

I have a 125amp Eaton breaker box. I'd like to know if I can replace the 30amp DP with a 40amp DP, add another 40amp DP, run 8 gauge wire, and still keep the same 125amp breaker box without doing damage or running the possibility of burning the condo down?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Ryan

Comment: How many square feet is the condo, what size is the feeder into your panel, how many kitchen branch circuits are present, and if you have electric heating appliances (dryer, range, HVAC), what are their nameplate ratings?

Comment: The condo is just under 1000 sqft. I'm not sure the size of the feeder line coming into the panel, I believe it's 2, 4 gauge wires.
HVAC - Min Ampacity 47.5/52.5
            Max Overcure Protection 50/60
Dryer - Can't find exact info, but it's on a 30amp DP
Range - Can't find exact info, but it's on a 40amp DP

Kitchen Circuits:
Microwave - 20amp 
Disposal/Dishwasher - 15amp DP
GFI - 20amp (x2)

Not sure if those specs help but I'll work on getting more info.

Comment: 1000sqf and a 50 amp MOP on the AC? That doesn't sound right. Where do you live... Hades? Anyway ;) are you sure it needs *two* 2-pole 40a breakers? If it does, do you really think you need that much recovery? Are you running a laundromat? ;p

Comment: Good ol Indiana. I save a lot during the summer months. Lol. I was looking at the Ecosmart Eco 18. It has 2 elements and each requires a 40amp DP with a ground for each. According to the Ecosmart website, that unit in this area will run 2 low flow showers.

Comment: I'd go at least 1 model up from that unless you're really only going to use 1 shower at a time. Their map is based on 105 degree outlet temp. Nobody sets their water heater at 105. Come winter time here I bet you're not going to be very happy.

Comment: Your service panel may be able to support this tankless heater. As another comment suggested go bigger! Or you will be taking cold showers with only the hot water turned on for 3+ months and a low flow shower head. Some models of electric tankless heaters require a 300 amp service to provide instant hot water at a rate close to a 80 gallon tank can provide. I have installed several on the west coast and used to live in Dayton OH. And would only go with on demand if natural gas is available because of the cost required to upgrade the panel.

Comment: Can you get us the nameplate ratings for the dryer and range please?

Comment: Can you post a clear photo of the electrical panel, and label each breaker in the photo with what it controls? That will allow us to determine if you can fit the additional breakers, both physically and electrically.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input. I finally broke down and had an electrician come out. I'm going to have to upgrade the box and meter in order to get the unit I want.